# C# count the number

Tags: c#, string, count, integer

My code is:

```
int num = 10;
int result;
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
  {
     result = i + num - 1;
     label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
  }
```

I should retrieve result = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 but i didn't retrieve it.

Comment: label1.Text will be overwritten at each iteration, that's one of the problems.

Comment: i don't get it. How can i get the sum of the numbers from 1 to 9 in this case?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, run the code, look at your code behavior. You'll see what the values are on each iteration and try to think what you can change to get to your desired sum.

Comment: It gives me 18 instead of 45, so it doesn't create 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9

Comment: @Sedax you are asking very basic questions today, How about taking some time and read some documents about string operations in c#.

Comment: It gives `18` because result is overwritten on each loop iteration, and `9 + 10 - 1 = 18`.

Comment: Is this a homework assignement?

Comment: kind of :-) i'm not so good and that's why i'm asking you guys.

Comment: @Sedax When you ask other people to solve your problems for you every time you run into the slightest hiccup then you don't learn how to solve problems on your own.  It only inhibits your own ability to learn.  Due to your repeated very low quality questions, you're also likely to be banned from asking further questions quite soon.

Comment: Servy, now i got it how to make it on my own, so now from you guys i learned how to make it on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment `result` by `i` inside the `for` loop and set `label1.Text` after the `for` loop. Try this:

```
int num = 10;
int result;
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
    result += i;
}
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add plus sign in front of equal.

```
label1.Text +=  + Convert.ToString(result) + "+";
```

Comment: This won't work: A) there is a + too much in your code. B) the code outputs 1+2+3+ instead of 1+2+3 (so the last + is too much)

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Sum().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

ekad's answer is the way to go. You could also do a slight variation:

```
int num = 10;
int result;
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
    result += i;
}
label1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When building strings, try to always use a StringBuilder. Change your code like this:

```
int num = 10;
int result;
string delimiter = "";
StringBuilder textForLabel = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
   result = i + num - 1;
   textForLabel.Add(delimiter + result);
   delimiter = ", ";
}
label1.Text = textForLabel.ToString();
```

This will output label1.Text as, "10, 11, 12, etc..."

I'm not going to give you the code for the sum of 1 to 9, but you should be able to figure it out from here.

Edit, I think user2720372 has the best solution to your answer.

Comment: i think is textForLabel.Append not .Add